# How to create a sorted table summary of the count of a categorical column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, sorting

I have a dataset like:

```
Animal  fruit
cat     apple
dog     grape
cat     cherry
cat     pear
dog     cherry
horse   melon
cat     lemon
```

I would like to create a summary table counting each occurance of an item in a specific column.

For example, in the programming language R, I can simply write:

```
count(data, Animal, sort=T)
```

which will return:

```
Animal  n
cat     4
dog     2
horse   1
```

How can I recreate this table summary in excel. There are many rows in the dataset and many categories. As a bonus, is there also a way to only include categories which occur more than once? (i.e. "horse" will not be included in the table above)

Comment: This site is not a free scripting site. If you have tried something and it did not work, share your code/scripts so we can help you debug it. But as it stands, this question will most likely be closed for lack of showing effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of accomplishing this task, here are few ways, i will like to use: Use as per your preferences :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _output, UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A8,COUNTIFS(A2:A8,A2:A8))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,"n"),FILTER(_output, DROP(_output,,1)>1)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _output, UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A8,MMULT(N(A2:A8=TOROW(A2:A8)),ROW(A2:A8)^0))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,"n"),FILTER(_output, TAKE(_output,,-1)>1)))
```

---

With newly inducted functions in `MS365` Beta Channel can use `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, GROUPBY(A1:A8,A1:A8,COUNTA,1,0),
     VSTACK({"Animal","n"},FILTER(α,TAKE(α,,-1)>1)))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     φ, PIVOTBY(A1:A8,,A1:A8,COUNTA,1,0),
     VSTACK({"Animal","n"}, FILTER(φ, DROP(φ,,1)>1)))
```

---

Or Using `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards Windows and MAC.

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Animal"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Animal"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Count] > 1)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: Amazing, thank you @Mayukh! Thank you for explaining it clearly as I'm obviously new to excel :)

Comment: Another, very simple method is to use consolidation with the function `Count`. However in a column at the right of data must be something. Cells which are empty would not be counted.